# AXIS2 web service with maven and tomcat,deployed as an aar

Tags: java, maven, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have a Web Service deployed (as an aar) file to Axis2, I Use this tutorial: https://www.rukspot.com/blog/axis_2_sample_web_service_with_maven_and_eclipse

I can get to the 'Services' page (http://localhost:7070/axis2/services/listServices)
It correctly shows my web service. I can click on that link to get the WSDL (http://localhost:7070/axis2/services/MyService?wsdl)
All good so far but I want to change **http** to **https**.
I know this has been ask over and over but I haven't (yet) found the solution for aar file, when I Copy the MyService.aar and paste to apache-tomcat/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/services the url is **http** by default (**http:**//localhost:7070/axis2/services/listServices) 
how can I Change It to **https** ? Any ideas?

Relevant info:
Intellij Idea,
Axis2,
JAVA 8,
Tomcat 8,
maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set https in your server.xml file by defining a new connector. If you do not have a keystore and a certificate (starting from scratch) I recommend you following the docs here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html